# erro com consulta EF e Mysql

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, datetime, linq-to-entities

tenho a seguinte consulta:

```
 var produto = (from a in context.ItensReceita
                join b in context.Receita on a.t0080_id_receita equals b.t0080_id_receita
                join c in context.Medicamento on a.t0080_id_receita equals c.t0051_id_medicamento     
                join d in context.Pessoa on b.t0031_id_paciente equals d.t0031_id_pesso
                   where b.t0020_id_empresa == idEmpresa
                   && Convert.ToDateTime(b.t0080_dt_venda) >= Convert.ToDateTime("2017/01/01")
                   && Convert.ToDateTime(b.t0080_dt_venda) <= Convert.ToDateTime("2017/01/31")
                   select new { b.t0080_dt_venda, d.t0031_nome, c.t0051_nome, a.t0081_lote, a.t0081_qtde, b.t0080_status });
```

porem da esse erro:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ToDateTime(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

nao esta aceitando a conversao de datas, como posso resolver isso ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 5):

O Linq não tem suporte ao método `ToDateTime`

O que você pode fazer é criar uma variável e depois utilizar ela na sua consulta

```
var data1 = Convert.ToDateTime("2017/01/01");
var data2 = Convert.ToDateTime("2017/01/31");
```

e usar essas duas variáveis na sua consulta

```
var produto = (from a in context.ItensReceita
                join b in context.Receita on a.t0080_id_receita equals b.t0080_id_receita
                join c in context.Medicamento on a.t0080_id_receita equals c.t0051_id_medicamento     
                join d in context.Pessoa on b.t0031_id_paciente equals d.t0031_id_pesso
                   where b.t0020_id_empresa == idEmpresa
                   && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(b.t0080_dt_venda) >= data1
                   && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(b.t0080_dt_venda) <= data2
                   select new { b.t0080_dt_venda, d.t0031_nome, c.t0051_nome, a.t0081_lote, a.t0081_qtde, b.t0080_status });
```

Um detalhe, é que você terá que usar o `DbFunctions.TruncateTime` que faz parte do `namespace` `System.Data.Entity`

Comment: Pablo, tentei da forma q vc sugeriu e deu o mesmo erro, acredito q seja pela tentativa de conversao da propriedade  && Convert.ToDateTime(b.t0080_dt_venda)

Comment: Sim, acabei de editar a resposta, não havia visto esse detalhe do seu campo dt_venda

Comment: Uma coisa, o seu dt_venda é um DateTime?

Comment: nao, é uma string, vou ter q mudar né...

Comment: Seria bom, @alessandremartins. Se você tá salvando uma data, é bom o campo ser um `DateTime`, não uma `string`.

Comment: Acho que seria mais conveniente mudar.

Comment: ao tentar usar o DbFunctions.TruncateTime, da isso no innerException: FUNCTION zulex01.TruncateTime does not exist, editei o post, veja a imagem la do Debug

Comment: Qual banco de dados você está utilizando?

Comment: banco de dados Mysql

Comment: veja se a function dessa resposta lhe ajuda http://stackoverflow.com/a/19731414/2221388 cria ela no teu banco de dados

Comment: bom, agora nao deu o erro mais de FUNCTION zulex01.TruncateTime does not exist, porem o Mysql espera a data no formato yyyy/MM/dd, o  DbFunctions.TruncateTime() pede um parametro do tipo dateTime, o dateTime precisa ser formatado para yyyy/MM/dd, todas as formatações q axei, a saida eh uma string.

Comment: Alessandre, acho que descobrir como usar o DbFunctions.TruncateTime caberia a uma outra pergunta.